# Flutter - FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen is not triggered

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using:

```
flutter version 2.2
firebase_messaging: ^10.0.2
```

I receive push notification, then click on it and the app is opened.
Then I do not see  `FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen` getting called (the callback is sending debug email to me, but I don't receive any)

My questions are

1. (optional) How can I debug android app with android studio debugur simulating case above, so app is killed not opened, then is opened via notification
2. What can be the issue here ? Why that stream is not triggered ? I initialise it in main.dart

PS: All other methods work fine, so if app is on foreground, onMessage.listen works great. I need to handle onMessageOpenedApp so I can redirect user to proper view based on notification information

Comment: do you find the solution? do you find a workaround for this? I have exactly the same issue , unfortunately your github issue you create is also has no answer and has been limited https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/6483

Comment: @Kristi Jorgji Any luck with a solution to this?  Ive been working on solving this for 3 days straight with no luck.  There can't be a bug this big in the framework, so we must be doing something wrong?

Answer (score 10):

For the first question:

To view the logs from your app, you can use the 'Logcat' tab in Android Studio or IntelliJ:
[image]

For the second question:

If your app is terminated and you want to receive a notification click callback, you should use:

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
  if (message != null) {
    // DO YOUR THING HERE
  }
});
```

, because according to the Flutter team's comments for onMessageopenedApp function:

```
 /// If your app is opened via a notification whilst the app is terminated,
  /// see [getInitialMessage].
```

Answer (score 8):

I've been in this issue for a while and just noticed that, there are 3 workarounds provided by `firebase_messaging` plugin.

1. initial message
2. onMessage
3. onMessageOpenedApp

You can find details below:

1. when app is in opened state `onMessage` callback will be called which is actually a `Stream<RemoteMessage>` and there will be no notification in notification tray. so you can handle it like

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      // handle accordingly
    });
```

2. when app is in pause state i.e. app is active in background, a notification will be appeared in notification tray and on click of that notification `onMessageOpenedApp` callback will be called which is also a `Stream<RemoteMessage>` so you can handle it like

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
      // handle accordingly
    });
```

3. third case is when app is in terminated or killed state. in that case notification will be shown in notification state but as your app is not in active state so that `Stream<RemoteMessage>` cannot be triggered. So in that case `firebase_messaging` provides you `getInitialMessage` callback which is actually a `Future<RemoteMessage?>`. you can use it like:

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
      if (message != null) {
        // handle accordingly
      }
    });
```

Note that `getInitializeMessage` callback will be triggered every time user opens the app if its handled in `main.dart` file. so maybe `message` is null, to prevent null pointer exception I put `if(message != null)` condition here

Answer (score 3):

To view logs when app is killed in your case, have you tried `flutter logs` command, just plug in your device in usb debugging and run `flutter logs` in you terminal all your `print` messages will show up here.

with regard to `FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen` getting called when app is launched is because you need to define the background messaging handler

```
/// Define a top-level named handler which background/terminated messages will
/// call.
///
/// To verify things are working, check out the native platform logs.
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
}
```

check the complete firebase_messaging example here [main.dart](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging/example/lib/main.dart)

Comment: Thanks, I have registered already the FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp but after I do one api call to fetch app config ? can that be the case that is being called late (before upgrade of firebase_messaging in old package worked fine like this), but maybe now is missing some event...

Comment: Right now I initialise firebase right away! on main.dart then later on after one api call do ```FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage((message) async {
      _logger.d('onBackgroundMessage: ${message.data}');
      _handle(message);
    });```. So should I initialise twice Firebase.initializeApp() like in the provided example, where second time is inside  _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler

Comment: Yes, one goes inside `Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) `

Comment: `_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler` is your top level function as in example.

Comment: I did this and still did not work..., before running app in main.dart I registered `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);` and function is top level looks like `/// Define a top-level named handler which background/terminated messages will
/// call.
///
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  getLogger('app_runner').d('Firebase.onBackgroundMessage: ${message.data}');
  PushNotificationsManager.handle(message);
}`

Comment: I moved it as first damn line in main.dart and now works.... i can see in logs getting called but have to sort out synchronisation with rest of app now, because i want to handle the notification after api call is done to see if user logged in etc then decide where to redirect them in which view based on notitifation type

Comment: No this is still not triggered!!! `onMessageOpenedApp` is not called, just onbackgroundmessage is called when app is closed... I want to handle action when user clicks on notitiation then app is opened (this worked great before upgrade new version)

Comment: can you once try upgrading to the firebase messaging firebase core package and try

Answer (score 1):

and in your manifest just add following code:

```
<intent-filter> <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> </intent-filter>
```

also make sure you have send "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"

from your server side like :

DATA='{ "notification": { "body": "this is a body", "title": "this is a title"         }, "data": { "att1": "value..",  "att2": "value..",         "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK", }, "to": "" }'