# Flutter notification open dialog when app is killed

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, background-process, firebase-notifications

I'm building an app using flutter with firebase notifications.

The app displays an alert dialog once a notification is received; it's working perfectly while I'm inside the app and while outside the app (in the background but the app isn't killed, I open the notification from the panel --> the app opens and an alert dialog is displayed).

However, when the app is killed I'm able to receive the notification in the panel but when I open the app the alert dialog is not displayed.

Here is some code that might be useful:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification? map = message.notification;
      if(map!.title == "Trip has ended"){
        try{
          showAlertDialog(navigatorKey.currentContext!, map!.title, map.body, null);
        }catch(e){print(e);}
        
      }
    });
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {

      RemoteNotification? map = message.notification;


      if(map!.title == "Trip has ended"){
        print("not listen trip end");

        try{
          showAlertDialog(navigatorKey.currentContext!, map!.title, map.body, null);
        }catch(e){print(e);}
        
      }

      
      

      if(map!.body != null ){
        if(map!.title == "Your driver is here"){
        String carImage = message.data['carImage'];
        print("receievedddd $carImage");
        try{
        showAlertDialog(navigatorKey.currentContext!, map!.title, map.body, carImage);
      }catch(e){print("error here $e");}
      }
      }
    });
```

Could someone help by suggesting what would be happening or any approach to tackling this problem?
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I refer some answers from other threads and resolved it by using this `getInitialMessage()`

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
  if (message != null) {
    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
    if (notification != null && android != null) {
    //  TODO
    //  Do any logic, for example dialog
    }
  }
});
```

References:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72497605/15075643
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68517166/15075643

Comment: Thanks man, it worked! Now the alert dialog appears for a second and then disappears, I guess it's due to the init state.
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Can you explain more about the "second" as you're mentioned. I am not too clear about that @MajdHarb . Do you put any dismiss countdown on that? Please share your code and we try to resolve it together.

Answer (score 0):

try this once

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
        showAlertDialog(navigatorKey.currentContext!,message.notification!.title.toString(), message.notification!.body, null);
  print('A new event was published!');
  message.data.clear();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I tried this, but unfortunately it didn't work. 
However, this is the solution. 
`FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage()`